# Angular 2 Quickstart for JS - what are "bundles" for?

Tags: javascript, angular

What is the point of the bundles in Angular 2?  My code (ES5) runs fine if I omit it in the quick start "My First Angular 2 App" example - is there something I'm missing?

Tutorial: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

I'm omitting this script: `node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-all.umd.js`

Here's the bundles directory in the latest build: https://github.com/angular/angular/tree/2.0.0-build.8516473.js/bundles

Answer (score 0):

Bundles ( compiled scripts )  are collection of barrels ( modules like "core","common","compiler" ).

Documentation of bundles:
https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-build.8516473.js/bundles/overview.md

UMD ( Universal Module Definition ) are created for ES5 and upgrading from ng1 to ng2.

Comment: Do you have it on GitHub or Plunker? Can i look at it.